# How Web page is a programming model to create ASP.Net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, webforms, asp.net-webpages

> ASP.NET Web Forms is a part of the ASP.NET web application framework. It is one of the three different programming models you can use to create ASP.NET web applications, the others being ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Pages.

I have read above lines in [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/what-is-web-forms) site. My understanding is ***A web page may refer to a html document retrieved from server*** and ***A Web Form is a thing in ASP.NET Application used to generate a HTML document(in dynamic manner)***

But definition of web forms said by asp.net site confused me. OK I can understand MVC is a programming model used to create ASP.NET Web application.

What is a Web Form ?  and What is a  Web page ?
  How Web page is a programming model to create ASP.Net web application

Comment: Scott Hanselman does a great overview of the different models in [this video](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/choosing-the-right-programming-model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net is Microsoft's technology stack for building dynamic web sites.

Within that stack, they support 3 different ways of generating a web page.

Web Forms is the oldest - it's been around since ASP.Net was born. It's tightly coupled into Visual Studio, and has "drag and drop" page building. Most people who care about how their HTML is constructed dislike Web Forms, because the "drag and drop" components can make it hard to generate semantic, valid HTML - though the latest version is a lot better.

ASP.Net MVC is an alternative to Web Forms - and it's a pretty decent MVC framework.

Web Pages is another alternative; it's more of a scripting/templating solution, similar to PHP. It doesn't have the overhead/safetynet of a proper framework behind it (like MVC), and it uses RAZOR to support the view engine.

For any non-trivial new projects, ASP.Net MVC is the industry standard.

Comment: Oh dear... I don't believe that last paragraph to be entirely accurate. If you're talking about something that is public/consumer facing then yes, I'd absolutely agree - however forms (even more so with the recent improvements in .NET 4 and the pending improvements in the next version) is a very *very* efficient mechanism for producing certain types of pages and will therefore retain a lot of traction (quite rightly) for internal applications a lot of which are decidedly non-trivial. Very little wrong with drag-drop coding where appropriate...

Comment: +1 for the *ASP.Net MVC is the industry standard.* I'd also remove the first part of the sentence.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, I do come at this from the PoV of public facing websites.
Having said that, most of the developers we interview seem to favour MVC, and most of them would prefer not to work on Web Forms - again, possibly because of the self-selecting audience...